# How to create n-number of rows based off a total value

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to generate multiple rows based off a single record from a list.

For example, I have a CSV file (e.g. **File A**) as follows:

| User ID | Total Value | Multiple Value | Remaining Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1007.25 | 11 | 7.25 |
| 456 | 804.25 | 9 | 4.25 |

I want to create another CSV file (e.g. **File B**) like this:

| User ID | Final Value |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 100.00 |
| 123 | 100.00 |
| 123 | 100.00 |
| 123 | 100.00 |
| 123 | 100.00 |
| 123 | 100.00 |
| 123 | 100.00 |
| 123 | 100.00 |
| 123 | 100.00 |
| 123 | 100.00 |
| 123 | 7.25 |
| 456 | 100.00 |
| 456 | 100.00 |
| 456 | 100.00 |
| 456 | 100.00 |
| 456 | 100.00 |
| 456 | 100.00 |
| 456 | 100.00 |
| 456 | 100.00 |
| 456 | 4.25 |

I tried using the pandas.concat function, along with a for loop, but I can't seem to get that to work properly (it errors out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the logic correctly, you can do this without the columns "Multiple Value" and "Remaining Value":

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard() # Your df here

df["Final Value"] = df["Total Value"].apply(lambda x: np.minimum(x - np.arange(0, x, 100), 100))

out = df[["User ID", "Final Value"]].explode("Final Value")
```

```
   User ID Final Value
0      123       100.0
0      123       100.0
0      123       100.0
0      123       100.0
0      123       100.0
0      123       100.0
0      123       100.0
0      123       100.0
0      123       100.0
0      123       100.0
0      123        7.25
1      456       100.0
1      456       100.0
1      456       100.0
1      456       100.0
1      456       100.0
1      456       100.0
1      456       100.0
1      456       100.0
1      456        4.25
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

```
User_ID_List = df["User ID"].to_list()

Multiple_Value_List = df["Multiple Value"].to_list()

Remaining_Value_List = df["Remaining Value"].to_list()

New_User_ID_List= []

New_Multiple_Value_List = []


for x in range(len(User_ID_List):
  Multiple_Value = Multiple_Value_List[x]
  for y in range(Multiple_Value):
     New_User_ID_List.append(User_ID_List[x])
     New_Multiple_Value_List.append(Multiple_Value_List[x])
  New_Multiple_Value_List.pop() 
  New_Multiple_Value_List.append(Remaining_Value_List[x])

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["User Id"] = New_User_ID_List
df["Final Value"] = New_Multiple_Value_List
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```py
import numpy as np

def spread(g):
    tot, rem, n = g[['Total Value', 'Remaining Value', 'Multiple Value']].squeeze()
    n -= 1
    val = (tot - rem) / n
    return np.r_[np.repeat(val, n), rem]

out = df.groupby('User ID').apply(spread).explode().to_frame('Final Value')

>>> out
        Final Value
User ID            
123      100.0     
123      100.0     
123      100.0     
123      100.0     
123      100.0     
123      100.0     
123      100.0     
123      100.0     
123      100.0     
123      100.0     
123       7.25     
456      100.0     
456      100.0     
456      100.0     
456      100.0     
456      100.0     
456      100.0     
456      100.0     
456      100.0     
456       4.25
```

Then:

```py
>>> print(out.to_csv())
User ID,Final Value
123,100.0
123,100.0
...
```

Or rather: `out.to_csv(my_file_b)`.